# Ubuntu 14.04 stuck at login after update

Tags: login

I did an update today and now the system is stuck at the login screen.  If I enter my password the screen goes blank then goes back to the login.  If I put in an incorrect password the system reports incorrect.

Comment: Sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm && sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing:
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

you should be able to fix it if you can access the terminal. Try running this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Followed by:

```
sudo reboot
```

This helped me when i had a similar issue.

Comment: And how should he fix it exactly? Maybe you can add this info to your answer.